# Unable to type the shortcut Command-Shift-B on Yosemite

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

On Yosemite (Mac OS X 10.10.4) I'm not able use the shortcut `Command`-`Shift`-`B`, while `Command`-`Shift`-`<another-letter>` works as expected.

I've double checked this in the Keyboard Viewer: pressing `Shift`, `Command` and `B` simultaneously won't show the `B` button as pressed.

That is, this is what I see when pressing the 3 buttons:

[image]

Same goes by pressing `Shift`-`Command` and then clicking the `B` in the Keyboard Viewer with the mouse pointer.

Is there any setting that might prevent the `B` from getting pressed?

Comment: Which app is in the foreground? Finder? Are you using any bluetooth devices? If enabled shift-cmd-B means: send file to bluetooth device (like your keyboard or mouse ;-))

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to note I had removed the shortcut of the "Send File To Bluetooth Device" service in the keyboard preferences. The problem here is I'm not even able to type the `B` with those 2 keys though, independently from the app.

Comment: Does this happen with all combinations of the left/right command and shift keys?

Comment: Yes, with all combinations

Comment: It would work depending what app is in front. For example open Firefox and use the shortcut and it will open the Bookmarks. In others which do not have it, it will sound a system alert.

Comment: On Firefox `cmd`-`shift`-`B` is *Show All Bookmarks* and it doesn't fire that command (`cmd`-`B` being *Show Bookmarks Sidebar*). In Atom `cmd`-`shift`-`B` should show the git status palette, but it won't.

Comment: Are you using Clipmenu? By default it binds `cmd+shift+b` to snippets menu. I had disable it to get the shortcuts to work in other programs.

Comment: @DerekKwok you're right! After disabling it, `cmd`-`shift`-`b` works now, thanks! If you want to add this as a "proper" answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have ClipMenu installed, the default key bind for the snippets menu is `CMD+Shift+B`.

To get this shortcut working in other programs, you'll need to either disable the shortcut or change it to another combination in ClipMenu Preferences:

[image: ClipMenu Preferences]

Comment: Such a life saver. The fork Clippy has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of a setting that would prevent the <kbd>B</kbd> from being pressed when modified by <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Assuming that you are not running any third party applications that may be affecting/altering keyboard shortcuts, such as Keyboard Maestro, I suggest you try the following:

Delete (move to trash and empty trash) the file `com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` from `/Users/YourName/Library/Preferences` and restart.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried but it doesn't work.